# How do I make the old status show? (discord.js)

Tags: if-statement, discord.js, status

This is the code I've got this far. I'd like the channel name to be eg. "Online-was-Offline" if I switch from offline to online. I only want the name to be this way when it changes from offline to online. If there is any other status change, eg: idle to online, I'd like it to only say the new status name. How would I do that?

```
setInterval(async () => {

        user = client.users.cache.get(config.user);
        updated = client.users.cache.get(config.user).presence.status;

        if(updated != status) {
            status = updated;


            if(updated == 'online') {
                channel.setName('Online');
            }
            if(updated == 'offline') {
                channel.setName('Offline');
            }
            if(updated == 'idle') {
                channel.setName('Idle');
            }
            if(updated == 'dnd') {
                channel.setName('DND');
            }

            message.edit(embed);
            
            
        } else {
            return
        }
    }, 1250);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the previous status value that is already stored in `status`:

```
setInterval(async () => {
    user = client.users.cache.get(config.user);
    updated = client.users.cache.get(config.user).presence.status;

    if(updated != status) {
        if(updated == 'online') {
            if (status == 'offline') {
                channel.setName('Online-was-Offline');
            } else {
                channel.setName('Online');
            }
        } else if(updated == 'offline') {
            channel.setName('Offline');
        } else if(updated == 'idle') {
            channel.setName('Idle');
        } else if(updated == 'dnd') {
            channel.setName('DND');
        }

        status = updated;
        message.edit(embed);
    } else {
        return
    }
}, 1250);
```

Some notes about the changes:

- `status = updated;` needs to be moved to *after* the `if` statement for this to work.
- Code untested but demonstrates a simple way of achieving this.
- Answer updated following comment from OP clarifying problem

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. What I'd like it to do is make the channel name say "Online from Offline" only if status changes from offline to online. If it eg. changes from idle to online, id like it to only say "online" and if it changes from anything else to anything else i'd only like it to say the new status. Thanks for any help!

Comment: @Carl I've revised the answer to (hopefully) provide what you've asked for.  Status will show as "`Online-was-Offline`" if it has changed from `offline` to `online`, otherwise will show the new status only.

Comment: Thank you! It looks right. I've got one more problem though. For some reason, when I added this, it says, "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ',' ". It is reffering to: `}, 1250);`.  You happen to know why?

Comment: @Carl You've probably missed a closing curly brace (`}`) somewhere.  I've tested the above code (exaclty as I put it in) and it does work, so I'm guessing a copy and paste error